# split column regex dataframe python

Tags: python, css, regex, dataframe, split

I have a column in a dataframe where in some rows I have the state, and sometimes just the city. For example in some rows I just have: 'Los Angeles', but in other rows I may have 'CA Los Angeles'.

I want to split that column into two new ones: states and cities, and if the state is not specified, then it can be blank. Something like this:

| COLUMN | STATE | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FL Miami | FL | Miami |
| Houston | null | Houston |

I was thinking by maybe splitting using regex like '[A-Z][A-Z]\s' or something like that but I cannot make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please reimport your data into Pandas with a proper (non space) separator between the two letter state and the city name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?:([A-Z]{2})\s+)?(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLFExl/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:([A-Z]{2})\s+)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `([A-Z]{2})` - Group 1: two uppercase ASCII letters
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

If you are using Pandas use

```py
df[['STATE','CITY']] = df['COLUMN'].str.extract(r'^(?:([A-Z]{2})\s+)?(.*)', expand=False)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I am attempting to do the same but need to use a specific named group from my regex. Would it be possible?

Comment: @RobertAlexander If you need a single column to extract to, use a single non-named capturing group.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor. As a matter of fact my regex has TWO capturing groups -> REGEX_STR = r"^(?P<primafirma>.+?)\s\((?P<gruppo>.+)\)" but I discovered that the Pandas str.extract function automatically creates a column for each capturing group with its name, so in my case this works very well:
df[["primafirma", "gruppo"]] = df["creatore"].str.extract(
    REGEX_STR, expand=False
)
splitting the original composition "creatore" column into its two elements as per the regex